# How to let Checked Checkbox get input value JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a form with the following elements: user Id, code number and a checkbox. The user will have to enter their User Id and Code number and check the checkbox to verify the code. Once the code is verified the form will proceed to the next form. In Javascript: How do I assign the input value from the code number element to the checkbox element? I know how to retrieve the code number from a mysql table but I am not able to figure out how to get the checked checkbox to get the user code number input. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide us with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing the html and the JavaScript code you already tried.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-dom-input-checkbox-value-property/amp/), but...The code number has it's own input right? Why does it need to be in the checkbox as well?

Comment: Sorry I miss this information when the checkbox is check will show pair the code number input with a secret code which is hidden. I know how to do that but I don't know how can I get the User code number input when checkbox is checked